# Debug why gradle caching fails across successful docker build instances?

Tags: docker, jenkins, gradle

I am looking at trying to make the gradle 6.9 cache work in a docker CI build invoked by Jenkins running in Kubernetes without access to scan.gradle.org.

The idea is to save an image after `gradle --build-cache --no-daemon classes bootJar` and use that as the ‘FROM‘ of subsequent builds. This works for me on my own machine, but I cannot make it work on the Jenkins server. Everything happens in the gradle home directory so everything should be cached.  I am wondering if the path to that matters, as it is deep in a Kubernetes mount under ‘/var‘ and this is the only differences between the two docker builds I can think of.

Caching would preferably be for the whole build, but just caching the Maven dependencies would be a substantial saving.

What am i missing? Is there a way to get insight in why Gradle decides to use what it has already or not?

Comment: What could work better would be to make HOME/.gradle a volume and share that folder across all of your containers. This would allow you to share the cache.

Comment: I have found that apparently `$HOME/.gradle` wasn't stored in the image but even changing GRADLE_HOME_DIR did not immediately give what I was looking for (but at least the artifacts are in the pushed image now)